# how to get the context of current document set in a custom web part placed on document set welcome page?

Tags: document-library, document-set, custom-web-parts

I want to create a web part to place on a document set web part.  How would I get the context of the document set and the documents within the set from within the web part?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url for the document set welcome page includes an ID in the query string, so you can use this parameter to find the document set:

http://server/MyDocumentLibrary/Forms/MyDocumentSet/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=2

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"]);
SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyDocumentLibrary"].GetItemById(id);
var dsItem = Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(item.Folder);
```

NOTE: You will need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement

Comment: Do you know how I can determine the library name knowing only the id of the item? i.e. id

Comment: In addition to the ID parameter, the welcome page also includes these query string parameters: FolderCTID (the content type), List (the List ID). So you can get the listId = ...QueryString["List"] and then: SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(listId)]

Comment: If your document set is in a sub folder (not at the root of the document library) you have to specify the RootFolder parameter. E.g. http://server/MyDocumentLibrary/Forms/MyDocumentSet/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=2&RootFolder=/MyDocumentLibrary/Folder1/DocumentSet1

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
```

will get you the ListItem, then

```
var folder = item.folder;
```

will get you the folder matching the item, and

```
var docset = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(folder);
```

will get you the document set for that folder. Though most things you might want to do (like getting/setting fields) really only need the listitem or maybe the folder.

Answer (score -1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-the-welcome-page-for-a-document-set-HA101782474.aspx says  "The Document Set Welcome page is a Web Part page that can be edited just as you would edit any Web Part page". Any further questions?

Comment: I understand that the welcome page is a web part page.  This doesn't answer the question.  If I put a web part on the welcome page (custom web part), programmatically how do I get a context to the current document set within the web part.  I want to perform operations on the documents within the current document set and to do this i need to get some sort handle the current set.  thx

Comment: This wasn't quite clear from how you formulated the question. Please edit the question to make it more specific. The question title is "how to add a webpart" while in the body you ask another question "how to get the context of the displayed document set".